# how to copy a folder from TFS to local drive

Tags: download, copy, shared-directory

i need to copy a folder from Team Foundation Server to my local drive .

i tried using the VersionControlServer class that have a Method named "DownloadFile" for single file download and i need to copy an entire folder.

how can i do that ?
an example code would really help.

Thanks !